# Obtaining specific values in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df those values are dictionaries:

```
df:                               
                                      A
    2017-05-31    {'price': '7.25', 'weight': 0.0, 'time': 4.05am}
    2017-06-01    {'price': '7.22', 'weight': 0.0 'time': 4.08am}
    2017-06-02    {'price': '7.24', 'weight': 0.0, 'time': 5.08am}
    2017-06-05    {'price': '7.25', 'weight': 0.0, 'time': 6.07am}
    2017-06-06    {'price': '7.19', 'weight': 0.0, 'time':3.33am}
    2017-06-07    {'weight': 0.0, 'price': 7.12, 'time':1.09am}
    2017-06-09    {'weight': 0.0, 'price': 7.46, 'time':2.08am}
```

I would like to obtain the values of the key `price` in each row. 
The desired output is

```
df:                               
                                  A
2017-05-31                       7.25
2017-06-01                       7.22
2017-06-02                       7.24
2017-06-05                       7.25
2017-06-06                       7.19
2017-06-07                       7.12
2017-06-09                       7.46
```

If the dictionaries were to follow  the same structure of `price-weight-time` I could simply apply a code like this:

```
format = lambda x: list(x.values())[0]
print(df.applymap(format))
```

However unfortunately this is not the case.

I was think of maybe sorting the dictionary values but I am not sure how to do it inside a df.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: I think `df['A'].apply(lambda x: x['price'])` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with lambda for select `key`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x['price'])
print (df)
               A
2017-05-31  7.25
2017-06-01  7.22
2017-06-02  7.24
2017-06-05  7.25
2017-06-06  7.19
2017-06-07  7.12
2017-06-09  7.46.
```

For all values use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
print (df1)
           price    time  weight
2017-05-31  7.25  4.05am     0.0
2017-06-01  7.22  4.08am     0.0
2017-06-02  7.24  5.08am     0.0
2017-06-05  7.25  6.07am     0.0
2017-06-06  7.19  3.33am     0.0
2017-06-07  7.12  1.09am     0.0
2017-06-09  7.46  2.08am     0.0
```

Comment: the OP wants 'price' key not 'time' no?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and pass a `lambda` to access the key of interest:

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x: x['price'])
```

Personally I'd avoid storing non-scalar values in a df as you lose any vectorised advantages of using pandas IMO. If the dict just has the same key-value pairs, I'd just expand the dict and store these keys as columns and values, then you can just do `df['price']` and perform vectorised arithmetic operations.

Comment: I will take into account your advice. Thank you